# Criteria for a character being a root of unity

Tags: rt.representation-theory, finite-groups

Let G be a finite group , g$\in$G and $\chi$ be a character of G. If |$\chi(g)$|=1 then show that $\chi(g)$ is a root of unity. $\\$

Hint: Let |G|=n and consider E=$\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{n})$ where $\zeta_{n}$ is a primitive nth root of unity.  Now let $\alpha$ be an algebraic integer in E with $|\alpha|$=1 and consider the minimal polynomial $f_{\alpha}$ and show that there are only finitely many such polynomials. But the question how do I show that and even if I show that how does it solve the problem.

---

**note added by Y. Choi, in case of confusion:** the question comes from Chapter 3 of Isaacs's book, and as is usual in the representation theory of finite groups, "character" means the trace of a finite-dimensional representation, not a homomorphism from $G$ into the multiplicative group of some field.

Comment: This looks like an assigned exercise from a textbook or a lecture course. If not, could you please say more about where you saw this statement and why you want to know the proof?

Comment: No it's not any homework

Comment: Am reading character theory by Issacs by myself.  It is an exercise from chapter 3 of the book. There is a hint given to the problem in the book but I don't understand it.

Comment: To the OP: why don't you include the hint in the question, and explain where you are stuck?

Comment: @René you do know that $\chi$ is not necessarily a HM, right? (just checking, sorry; I just wasn't sure what you were getting at in your hint)

Comment: @YemonChoi: I'm sorry, I was mistaken then. I will delete my "hint". Thanks for alerting me to this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem has little to do with representation theory, other than the fact that
the eigenvalues of a matrix of finite order are roots of unity. If $\alpha$ lies in a cyclotomic extension $K$ of $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\lvert\alpha\rvert=1$, then all the conjugates $\alpha^g$ (where $g$ lies in the Galois group of $K$) of $\alpha$ satisfy $\lvert\alpha^g\rvert=1$ since the Galois group of a cyclotomic extension is abelian, so $g$ commutes with complex conjugation. Now use [Kronecker's theorem](https://books.google.ca/books?id=qIJPxdwSqlcC&pg=PA175), where the proof follows Isaac's hint.

Answer (score 4):

The key to this question is ( I believe) that characters take values in cyclotomic number fields, so that complex conjugation is central in the relevant Galois group. From the fact that $|\chi(g)| = 1,$ it follows that all algebraic conjugates of $\chi(g)$ have absolute value $1$.

It is a standard fact that if all algebraic conjugates of an algebraic integer $\alpha$ have  absolute value $1$, then $\alpha$ is a root of unity. I only outline a sketch of the proof of this standard fact. Note that all powers of $\alpha$ have the same property. On the other hand, there are only finitely many possibilities for the minimum polynomials of powers of $\alpha,$ so the powers of $\alpha$ are not all distinct. Hence $\alpha$ is indeed a root of unity.

Comment: This standard fact is the kind of thing many of us analysts never saw - or perhaps forgot through lack of use :)

Comment: @YemonChoi : My comments were only made because I wanted to make it clear that this was a well-known fact ( at least to algebraic number theorists, of which I am not one). Richard Stanley attributes it to Kronecker in his answer- I myself was unaware that this was the origin of the result.

Comment: @YemonChoi   Once we know $\forall \sigma \in Gal(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)/\mathbb{Q}),|\sigma(\alpha)| = 1$ we know $\forall m, \forall \sigma \in Gal(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)/\mathbb{Q}),|\sigma(\alpha^m)| = 1$. Expressing the coefficients of the minimal polynomial of $\alpha^m$ (at most of degree $n$) in term of its roots, they are bounded by some constant independently of $m$, and what Geoff Robinson said follows : there are finitely many such possible polynomials so $\alpha^l = \alpha^m$ for some $l,m$

Comment: Thanks @user1952009 -- I could follow Geoff's outline, I was merely remarking that it is not something I remember learning!